# Vertica dynamic pivot/transform

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table in vertica :

```
id   Timestamp    Mask1       Mask2
------------------------------------------- 
 1    11:30         50         100
 1    11:35         52         101 
 2    12:00         53         102
 3    09:00         50         100
 3    22:10         52         105
 .     .            .           .
 .     .            .           .
```

Which I want to transform into :

```
 id    rows     09:00    11:30    11:35     12:00     22:10     ....... 
-------------------------------------------------------------- 
 1     Mask1     Null     50       52       Null       Null     ....... 
       Mask2     Null     100      101      Null       Null     ....... 
 2     Mask1     Null     Null     Null     53         Null     .......     
       Mask2     Null     Null     Null     102        Null     .......
 3     Mask1     50       Null     Null     Null       52       .......     
       Mask2     100      Null     Null     Null       105      .......
```

The dots (...) indicate that I have many records.

1. Timestamp is for a whole day and is of format hours:minutes:seconds starting from 00:00:00 to 24:00:00 for a day (I have just used hours:minutes for the question).
2. I have defined just two extra columns Mask1 and Mask2. I have about 200 Mask columns to work with.
3. I have shown 5 records but in real I have about a million record.

What I have tried so far:

1. Dumping each records based on id in a csv file.
2. Applying transpose in python pandas.
3. Joining the transposed tables.

The possible generic solution may be pivoting in vertica (or UDTF), but I am fairly new to this database.

I am struggling with this logic for couple of days. Can anyone please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want a column for every second in a day, 86400? Does Vertica support so many columns in a Select?

Comment: I am totally new to this. RDBMS would certainly raise some issue but I don't know about vertica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the solution as I would code it for just the time values that you have in your data examples.

If you really want to be able to display all 86400 of `'00:00:00'` through `'23:59:59'`, though, you won't be able to. Vertica's maximum number of columns is 1600.

You could, however, play with the Vertica function `TIME_SLICE(timestamp::TIMESTAMP,1,'MINUTE')::TIME`

(TIME_SLICE takes a timestamp as input and returns a timestamp, so you have to cast (`::`) back and forth), to reduce the number of rows to 1440 ...

In any case, I would start with `SELECT DISTINCT timestamp FROM input ORDER BY 1;`, and then, in the final query, would generate one line per found timestamp (hoping they won't be more than 1598....), like the ones actually used for your data, into your query:

```
, SUM(CASE timestamp WHEN '09:00' THEN val END) AS "09:00"
, SUM(CASE timestamp WHEN '11:30' THEN val END) AS "11:30"
, SUM(CASE timestamp WHEN '11:35' THEN val END) AS "11:35"
, SUM(CASE timestamp WHEN '12:00' THEN val END) AS "12:00"
, SUM(CASE timestamp WHEN '22:10' THEN val END) AS "22:10"
```

SQL in general has no variable number of output columns from any given query. If the number of final columns varies depending on the data, you will have to generate your final query from the data, and then run it.

Welcome to SQL and relational databases ..

Here's the complete script for your data. I pivot vertically first, along the "Mask-n" column names, and then I re-pivot horizontally, along the timestamps.

```
\pset null Null
-- ^ this is a vsql command to display nulls with the "Null" string
WITH 
-- your input, not in final query
input(id,Timestamp,Mask1,Mask2) AS (
          SELECT 1 ,  TIME '11:30'    ,    50    ,    100
UNION ALL SELECT 1 ,  TIME '11:35'    ,    52    ,    101
UNION ALL SELECT 2 ,  TIME '12:00'    ,    53    ,    102
UNION ALL SELECT 3 ,  TIME '09:00'    ,    50    ,    100
UNION ALL SELECT 3 ,  TIME '22:10'    ,    52    ,    105
)
,
-- real WITH clause starts here
-- need an index for your 200 masks
i(i) AS (
  SELECT MICROSECOND(ts) FROM (
            SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MICROSECOND,  1,TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01') AS tm
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MICROSECOND,200,TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01') AS tm
  )x
  TIMESERIES ts AS '1 MICROSECOND' OVER(ORDER BY tm)
)
,
-- verticalised masks
vertical AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , i
  , CASE i 
      WHEN   1 THEN 'Mask001' 
      WHEN   2 THEN 'Mask002' 
      WHEN 200 THEN 'Mask200' 
    END AS rows
  , timestamp
  , CASE i
      WHEN   1 THEN Mask1 
      WHEN   2 THEN Mask2 
      WHEN 200 THEN 0 -- no mask200 present
    END AS val
  FROM input CROSS JOIN i
  WHERE i <=2 -- only 2 masks present currently
)
-- test the vertical CTE ...
-- SELECT * FROM vertical order by id,rows,timestamp;
-- out  id | i |  rows   | timestamp | val 
-- out ----+---+---------+-----------+-----
-- out   1 | 1 | Mask001 | 11:30:00  |  50
-- out   1 | 1 | Mask001 | 11:35:00  |  52
-- out   1 | 2 | Mask002 | 11:30:00  | 100
-- out   1 | 2 | Mask002 | 11:35:00  | 101
-- out   2 | 1 | Mask001 | 12:00:00  |  53
-- out   2 | 2 | Mask002 | 12:00:00  | 102
-- out   3 | 1 | Mask001 | 09:00:00  |  50
-- out   3 | 1 | Mask001 | 22:10:00  |  52
-- out   3 | 2 | Mask002 | 09:00:00  | 100
-- out   3 | 2 | Mask002 | 22:10:00  | 105
SELECT
  id
, rows
, SUM(CASE timestamp WHEN '09:00' THEN val END) AS "09:00"
, SUM(CASE timestamp WHEN '11:30' THEN val END) AS "11:30"
, SUM(CASE timestamp WHEN '11:35' THEN val END) AS "11:35"
, SUM(CASE timestamp WHEN '12:00' THEN val END) AS "12:00"
, SUM(CASE timestamp WHEN '22:10' THEN val END) AS "22:10"
FROM vertical
GROUP BY
  id
, rows
ORDER BY
  id
, rows
;
-- out Null display is "Null".
-- out  id |  rows   | 09:00 | 11:30 | 11:35 | 12:00 | 22:10 
-- out ----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
-- out   1 | Mask001 |  Null |    50 |    52 |  Null |  Null
-- out   1 | Mask002 |  Null |   100 |   101 |  Null |  Null
-- out   2 | Mask001 |  Null |  Null |  Null |    53 |  Null
-- out   2 | Mask002 |  Null |  Null |  Null |   102 |  Null
-- out   3 | Mask001 |    50 |  Null |  Null |  Null |    52
-- out   3 | Mask002 |   100 |  Null |  Null |  Null |   105
-- out (6 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (6 rows): 28.143 ms. All rows formatted: 28.205 ms
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will check and revert back soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` to unpivot the data and then conditional aggregation:

```
select id, which,
       max(case when timestamp >= '09:00' and timestamp < '09:30'  then mask end) as "09:00",
       max(case when timestamp >= '09:30' and timestamp < '10:00' then mask end) as "09:30",
       max(case when timestamp >= '10:00' and timestamp < '10:30' then mask end) as "10:00",
       . . .
from ((select id, timestamp,
              'Mask1' as which, Mask1 as mask
       from t
      ) union all
      (select id, timestamp, 'Mask2' as which, Mask2 as mask
       from t
      ) 
     ) t
group by t.id, t.which;
```

Note:  This includes the `id` on each row.  I strongly recommend doing that, but you could use:

```
select (case when which = 'Mask1' then id end) as id
```

If you really wanted to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought of using case but the problem is I have timestamps for every second in a day as well as I have a huge number of columns. Won't it create a problem ? (Please check the meta information I have added along with the question)

Comment: @SayantanMukherjee . . . This answers the question that you originally asked.  If it doesn't answer the question you *wanted* to ask, you should ask another question.  That said, I don't see a problem with having more masks.  The `union all` should be fairly efficient in Vertica because it is a columnar database.  But there are other ways to unpivot the data if a union with 200 table references exceeds the capacity of the database.

Comment: Thanks. Will try and comment back.